# How do I enumerate the following list?

Tags: python, enumeration

I am trying to enumerate the following list but the output I get is not correct:

```
colours = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
for p, colours in enumerate(colours): 
    print(p, ("-->"), colours[p])
```

The output I get is:

```
0 --> r
1 --> r
2 --> u
3 --> l
```

which is not what I am after of course, any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please tag with programming language.

Comment: I don't know what programming language this is, but it looks like you are redefining `colours` in the `for` statement, which means that the `colours` in `print` statement is not the one from line 1. You are printing the diagonal: [r]ed, g[r]een, bl[u]e, yel[l]ow.

Comment: HI sorry, this is Python!

Comment: How would I correct it? Add brackets somewhere?

Comment: Give the second variable a different name, like `colour` instead of `colours`.

Comment: If you are using `enumerate` you don't need to access the values via index, so `colours[p]` is at best pointless. Use something like `print (p, ("-->"), colour)`

Answer (score 1):

```
colours = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
for p, colour in enumerate(colours): 
    print (f"{p} --> {colour}")
```

1st: don't use same name for element of a loop as a variable you are iterating.
2nd: what output are you expecting? Single line when printing? This would be done in my update. It puts variables in f-string.